Apache Spark makes kinit with user specified in jdbc connection options instead of using cached ticket
I'm trying to connect from Hadoop cluster to GreenPlum database in Kerberized environment.
Simple java JDBC application connects successfully.
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd)) {
    ResultSet resultSet = conn.prepareStatement("select 1").executeQuery();
    resultSet.next();
    resultSet.getInt(1);
    System.out.println("Connection successful.");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

But Spark application fails to connect.
ss = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
ss.read().format("jdbc")
        .option("url", url)
        .option("user", user)
        .option("dbschema", schema)
        .option("dbtable", table)
        .load()
        .show();

I start java JDBC program like this:
java -jar -Djava.security.auth.login.config=pgjdbc.conf -Dsun.security.jgss.debug=true ./test-jdbc-connection-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar param:url=<URL> param:user=<GP_USER>

and get the following output:
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache true useKeyTab false doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is false principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Acquire TGT from Cache
Principal is <HDP_PRINCIPAL>
Commit Succeeded

Search Subject for Kerberos V5 INIT cred (<HDP_PRINCIPAL>, sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential)
Connection successful.

where <HDP_PRINCIPAL> is my correct principal.
The Spark application is launched with this script:
export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=3
spark-submit \
        --name "test_GP_connect" \
        --master yarn \
        --deploy-mode "client" \
        --queue <MY_YARN_QUEUE> \
        --conf ..... \
        ........
        --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dsun.security.jgss.native=true -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -Dsun.security.jgss.debug=true -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.auth.login.config=pgjdbc.conf " \
        --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dsun.security.jgss.native=true -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -Dsun.security.jgss.debug=true -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.auth.login.config=pgjdbc.conf " \
        --num-executors 1 \
        --executor-memory 20g \
        --driver-memory 5g \
        --files pgjdbc.conf \
        --jars ./gsp.jar \
        --class ru.pal.testsparkjdbcconn.Main \
        test-spark-jdbc-conn-3.0.jar \
        param:url=<URL> \
        param:user=<GP_USER> \
        param:schema=<GP_SCHEMA> \
        param:table=<GP_TABLE>

and gives the following output:
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache true useKeyTab false doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is false principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Acquire TGT from Cache
......................
get normal credential
Principal is <HDP_PRINCIPAL>
Commit Succeeded 

Search Subject for Kerberos V5 INIT cred (<GP_USER>, sun.security.jgss.wrapper.GSSCredElement)

As you can see, Spark tries to kinit wiht <GP_USER>!!! instead of using <HDP_PRINCIPAL>
Exception is:
Exception in thread "main" com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: GSS Authentication failed
        ......
        at ru.pal.testsparkjdbcconn.Main.main(Main.java:85)
        ......
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: GSS Authentication failed
        ......
        ... 25 more
Caused by: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Can't find client principal <GP_USER>@<HDP_REALM> in cache collection)
        ......
        ... 40 more

PS. pgjdbc.conf contains this:
pgjdbc {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
isInitiator=true
useTicketCache=true
useKeyTab=false
renewTGT=false
doNotPrompt=true
debug=true
;
};

PPS.
Looks like it is the PostgreSQL JDBC driver who makes this "kinit", so maybe it is the reason of this strange behaviour.

Upgrading PostgreSQL JDBC driver version (to 42.7) solved the problem. It was difficult though to give the Spark the proper version of the driver, because the Spark itself has the PgJDBC driver inside. And that driver version is old.
Everything worked when I specified
--driver-class-path postgresql-42.7.3.jar \
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=postgresql-42.7.3.jar \
--conf spark.executorEnv.KRB5CCNAME=krb5cc \
--files pgjdbc.conf,$KRB5CCNAME#krb5cc \
--jars gsp.jar,postgresql-42.7.3.jar \
--class ru.pal.testsparkjdbcconn.Main \
test-spark-jdbc-conn-3.0.jar \

Also I added kerberos creds cache to --files, specifying it for the executors with --conf spark.executorEnv.KRB5CCNAME=krb5cc
